# Scrum vs Kanban. What are advantages and disadvantages?

Tags: agile

What are advantages and disadvantages of Scrum over Kanban methodology.
Which one is better for mobile development?

Comment: Official differences : https://www.atlassian.com/agile/kanban/kanban-vs-scrum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR; You don't have an Apples to Apples comparison here.

- Scrum is am empirical framework optimised for delivering Software
- Kanban is an empirical method of optimising any existing process

### Kanban

Kanban needs way more discipline in your team and organisation to be able to get value. You start by modelling your current processed and then make small incremental changes to the process to optimise it for your needs. Most teams fail to optimise effectively and end up where they started (or close to it) forever.

*Kanban is not focused on Software Delivery and is best suited to tasks that have a relatively small standard deviation in size of batches. This allows you to monitor flow and optimise for it.*

### Scrum

Scrum is a Framework that enshrines accountability, inspection and adaption, and transparency as its fundamental pillars. The three clear roles provide accountability so everyone knows what they have to do. Each and every one of the Events provides a Kaizan moment to allow you to change. Every one of the Artefacts creates transparency so we all know what is going on.

The most important artefact is the Increment of Working Software because that is what out goal is. You can read the Scrum Guide to find out how it all goes together.

*Scrum is focused only on Software Delivery (although modified versions like EduScrum exist) and is best suited for tasks that have a large standard deviation in batch sizes.*

#### Conclusion

There is no 'better' option, its what works for you. I see more teams succeed quicker using Scrum than Kanban.

If you bought the board game monopoly would you expect it to come with a rule book or a strategy guide? Right, a rule book. Will the rules help you win? No, you will need to come up with, and experiment with, strategies that work for you.

- The Scrum Guide is the rule book for Scrum
- In Kanban you come up with your own rule book as you go along

All the practices common to either technique are complimentary.